# imacros javascript getElementsByClassName undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom, imacros

Im getting the above error because the script tries to load "var ul" before loading the page {{!COL1}}. How do I get it to run only after the page loads.

```
 var macro;
 macro =  "CODE:";
 macro += "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\imacros\\artmi.csv" + "\n";
 macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 3" + "\n"
 macro += "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}" + "\n";
 var ul = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("vd-doc")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
 for (var i = 0; i < ul.length; ++i) {
 macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:*" + "\n";
 macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
 macro += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\imacros FILE=artmi23.csv" + "\n";
 }
 iimPlay(macro);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Put your code here ...
});
```

Comment: Missing a bit of logic as it doesnt get to  run at all when tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
var macro;
 macro =  "CODE:";
 macro += "SET !DATASOURCE C:\\imacros\\artmi.csv" + "\n";
 macro += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 3" + "\n"
 macro += "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}" + "\n";

 for (var i = 0; i < ul.length; ++i) {
 macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:*" + "\n";
 macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n";
 macro += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\imacros FILE=artmi23.csv" + "\n";

 iimPlay(macro);

var ul = window.content.document.getElementsByClassName("vd-doc")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
 }
```

This code makes more sense.

Comment: Check some more what is in CSV file.

Comment: Didnt get any data across to the csv file.